# Dynamic routing by id

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to display content based on the ID, I am trying to make the id switching from my menu. I am having trouble setting up the id.. channelName holds all the channels with different Id's. When I click on an item, I want specific content to the ID to be displayed.

```
    router-link(:to="{name: 'ChannelPaths', params: {id: findId }}" v-for="channel in channelName" :key="channel.id" tag="p")
```

```
  {
    path: "channels/:id/messages",
    name: "ChannelPaths",
    component: Content,
    props: true
  }
```

```
 ...mapState({
      channelName: (state) => state.channels.fetchChannels,
    }),
    findId() {
      return this.channelName.find(ch => ch.channel_id)
    }
```

API example

```
 {
        "message_id": "844646e9-648d-4a06-aa1a-f747133601f9",
        "description": null,
        "timestamp": null,
        "email": null,
        "channel_id": "d17b7638-d758-4c91-b852-fa1f939e3671",
        "channel_name": "Test"
    },
```

```
 fetchChannelMessages({commit,}, id) {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/channels/${id}/messages`)
        .then((res) => {
            commit(SET_CHANNEL_MSG, res.data);
        }).catch(e => console.log(e))
    },
```

```
.content__msg-list--message.d-flex(v-for="msg in messageList", :key="msg.id")
      .d-flex.align-items-center.content__msg-left
        b-avatar.mr-3(variant="secondary")
        p.mb-0 {{ msg.description }}
        span#time.mb-0 {{ msg.timestamp }}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `findId` be either `channel.id` or `channel.channel_id`?  (You've used both properties)  It can't be a computed because it's in a `v-for`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is available in the object you are iterating.

```
router-link(:to="{name: 'ChannelPaths', params: {id: channel.channel_id }}" v-for="channel in channelName" :key="channel.channel_id" tag="p")
```

Perhaps it is `channel.id` and not `channel.channel_id`. I cant tell from your example.

If you needed the id from a name, you would use a method, not a computed.

```
findId(channelName) {
      return this.channelName.find(ch => ch.channel_name === channelName).channel_id
    }
```

Comment: the routing seem to work, but it won't display any content in it. I've edited my post and added code at the bottom - could you have a look if Im doing something wrong?